# In android how do I call StartActivity() from a global function?

Tags: android, android-activity, global, start-activity

So I'm trying to make a Logout function that all the logout butotns would call.

I found this page [creating global functions in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485095/creating-global-functions-in-android)

and I started coding a global function, and it refuses to recognize startActivity()

Here's my code

```
import android.content.Intent;

public class Utilities {


public static void Logout(){
    System.out.println("Logging Out");
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
 }
}
```

getBaseContext() also gives me an error but I was able to find another fix for that (I think, haven't been able to test it).

Answer (score 3):

You will need the activity context.

```
 public class Utilities {
 public static void Logout(Context context){
 Log.i("Utilities","Logging Out");
 Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(i);
 }
 }
```

`startActivity` is a method of your activity class. So you will need the activity context.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Comment: +1 Good explanantion! I forgot to add WHY to pass the `Activity` `Context`

Comment: So I would call that in the thread with Utilities.logout(getBaseContext()) ?

Comment: Oh yeah you should replace getBaseContext() with something

Comment: @user2312638 use activity context ie `context`.

Comment: @user2312638 use `Utilities.logout(MyActivityName.this)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing `Context` of the `Activity` to it.

```
public class Utilities {

    public static void Logout(Context c) {
        System.out.println("Logging Out");
        Intent i = new Intent(c, MainActivity.class);
        c.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

So when you call it from an `Activity`

However, another way to do this is to create a `BaseActivity` which `extends Activity` and have the function in there. Then extend all of your `Activities` from `BaseActivity` and use an `<include` tag to include the `Button` in each `layout` file maybe as a header, footer, or whatever.

```
Utlities.Logout(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add param of your current activity (`from`).  Then call your static method with it.

```
public static void Logout(Activity from){
    System.out.println("Logging Out");
    Intent i = new Intent(from, MainActivity.class);
    from.startActivity(i);
 }
}
```